# AddEventListener only triggers once

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to change the color of a paragraph when i click it, but it only happens once:

```js
//ejercicio 5b
function modifyColor(){
    this.style.color = "green"? "blue":"green";
}
let ej5P = document.getElementById("datos2");
ej5P.addEventListener("click", modifyColor);
```

```css
body{
    background-color: lightcoral !important;
}

.container{
    margin:100px;

    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="parcial.js" defer></script>
    <title>Parcial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="ejercicio">

            <p id="datos2">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur <span id="span_color"> adipisicing elit.</span> At, repellendus neque maxime atque consectetur quidem corrupti sunt fugit quos quas.
            </p>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried writing the function inside the eventlistener, but it has the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your condition. `"green"` always evaluates to true as it is a non-empty string.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
function modifyColor(){
    this.style.color = this.style.color === "green" ? "blue" : "green";
}
```

I'd recommend to do this using classes btw.

```
// The 'toggle' function will handle the add/remove class logic.
function modifyColor(){
        this.classList.toggle('highlight');
    }
```